# Ajax doesn't work on Opera and Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, microsoft-edge, opera

I've made a social media website and I had to create an algorithm for displaying posts.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

        oReq.open("get", "in.php");

        var cos;

        oReq.onload = function m() {

            cos = this.responseText;

            $("#infinite").append(cos);
        };
        oReq.send();
   }
});
```

In PHP, I use echo to pass what I need to js. I came across few problems: ajax works slowly on Microsoft Edge and does not work on Opera. When I refresh the page it does not work on any browser. Why? Is it a good idea for displaying content?

Comment: When something "does not work" usually there is an error..if you of course are trying to do basic debugging

Comment: I see "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" at line 16 in my js, but I can't find this error in my code, it seems to be ok.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? Could you please provide [a minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code which can reproduce the issue? The code you provide seems can't reproduce the error you mention in the comment. Besides, you can try to clear browser cache and try again.